# How can i resize <div> Element with flexigrid in <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, flextable

html data

```
<div id="flexdiv" class="resizable-ui">
<div> etc layer .. </div>

<table class='flexme1'>
...
</table>

</div>
```

### jquery data

```
    var width = $(div).width(),
        height = $(div).height()-100;

     $('.flexme1').flexigrid({
         width: width,
         height: height,
         resizable: false,
         singleSelect: true});



$(div).resize(function() {
          var width = $(div).width(),
              height = $(div).height() -20;
          $('.flexme1').flexigrid({height:height,width:width,striped:false});
        });
```

it is not working
i don't know what is it problem
help me angles!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! plz..

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve here? there are two div elements, which one do you want to resize and when??

Comment: one obvious problem here is that the div variable you're using doesn't have anything so code will not go any further than that line! so you should at the start write this: var div = document.getElementById("flexdiv"); i checked and now you will get the width: 501 and height 40! when you sibtract 100 from height it gives -60

Comment: I wnat to resize "<div id="flexdiv">" element 
 This also changes the size "<table class='flexme1'>" should be changed.

Comment: so you want to resize flexdiv and then set the height of table flexme1 20 less than the height of flexdiv?

Comment: ok wait.. i'll fix it

Comment: 'flexdiv' would like to change the size of 'flexme1' is also change the size.

Comment: @AbdulJabbar Hey I'm late sorry, mm.. flexigrid is api.
And My question is the table (row,collum etc..) resize using api
So, your comment very helpful but not correct.. 
Thank you anyway angle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have written the code where you can resize both div and table element:

```
<div id="flexdiv" class="resizable-ui" style="border: 1px solid">
<div> etc layer .. </div>

<table id="table1" class='flexme1' style="border: 2px dotted; width:200px; height:200px">
</table>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var div = document.getElementById("flexdiv");
var width = $(div).width(),
height = $(div).height();

alert("Div-OldHeight: "+ height);
alert("Div-OldWidth: "+ width);
var newHeight = "600px";
var newWidth = "400px";
div.style.height = newHeight;
div.style.width = newWidth;
alert("Div-NewHeight: "+ newHeight);
alert("Div-NewWidth: "+ newWidth);

var table = document.getElementById("table1");
width = $(table).width(),
height = $(table).height();

alert("Table-OldHeight: "+ height);
alert("Table-OldWidth: "+ width);
var newHeight = "100px";
var newWidth = "100px";
table.style.height = newHeight;
table.style.width = newWidth;
alert("Table-NewHeight: "+ newHeight);
alert("Table-NewWidth: "+ newWidth);
```

I have placed the new Width and height in variables, you can change them according to your needs, hopefully you will get the basic idea of how to do it. You can also make table dependent on the size of div, basic core will remain the same as i have provided you..

**[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/uuntnhts/)**